In a custom network protocol that prepends messages with their length, how do you prevent malicious packets from causing memory exhaustion?
For learning purposes, I'm writing a basic network protocol over TcpStreams. In order to delimit individual messages, I was using read_until, but because the data sent can contain any bytes, this can't work.
So the next best option seems to be to prepend every message with the length and then read that many bytes from the stream.
Naively, this could be implemented as such:
fn read(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut length_buffer = [0_u8; 8];
    stream.read_exact(&mut length_buffer); // Ignoring errors for the example
    let length = u64::from_le_bytes(length_buffer);

    let mut result = vec![0_u8; length as usize];
    stream.read_exact(&mut result); // Ignoring errors for the example

    result
}

However, let's imagine a server is using this read function. A malicious user could send a packet: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255], causing the server to attempt to allocate 18446744073709551615 bytes of memory, which will obviously fail and crash the program.
How could you deal with this? Options I can think of are:

Hardcode a limit on the maximum packet size
Catch the memory exception and continue? (Rust specifically panics on a "capacity overflow", so this would entail accepting that a worker thread dies)

But neither of these seem right. What is done in practice for public-facing server protocols?

"Hardcode a limit on the maximum packet size" - yes, that's generally how most network protocols are defined, in my experience. There will be a maximum length set for each defined field, for example, something like a text chat message might have an imposed protocol-defined max-length of 1KiB (1024 bytes) - and something like a binary response might be 2GiB (which is conveniently 2^31-1).

Thanks for the insight! That doesn't seem like a scalable solution though - if my system has 16 GiB of ram, then my memory can be exhausted by eight such 2 GiB packets. I feel like I'm missing some obvious solution, but perhaps I'm just overthinking the problem.

You wouldn't be pre-allocating a buffer all in-memory. Consider how web-servers (going back to the 1990s) processed incoming PUT requests where the request headers might say Content-Length: 10GB: they never blindly trusted the Content-Length header and they worked by only buffering the first few KB in-memory and if the request ever got longer than the request-body stream was redirected to a file-stream on-disk. If the actual amount of data sent wasn't exactly equal to the claimed Content-Length  then the request was rejected.

That makes sense, thanks!

@Dai, don't you think this counts as an answer? It's not opinion-based (as the close votes are suggesting), it's based on the previous experience in the similar matter, so it seems to be acceptable?

@Cerberus I've started writing a long-form of my comment-reply and I'm already 6 paragraphs in and not even half-way done - and it's midnight. I'm now regreting my life-choices.
